# One form for multiple twig views - Symfony4

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

:)
How can I pass one form to multiple twig views?
I have a search bar that I want to pass to every view
I created form and it's controller and then I have tried to paste this into base template:

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\SearchbarController::searchAction')) }}
```

but got error

> Maximum function nesting level of '1024' reached, aborting!

My action in controller:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(searchbarFormType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $name = $form['name']->getData();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('search_result', [
            'name' => $name,
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('partials/searchbar.html.twig', [
      'searchbarFormType'  => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Do you know how could I solve my problem? or you know better solution?

Comment: creating the form - and handling the form doesnt neccessarily be needed in the same method. 

you could create the form in a twig extension for example which just returns `->createView()`

Answer (score 0):

https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html#using-a-twig-extension

Or another solution - do a function that returns the form, but it will be uglier;)